# Entity Framework - multiple entities from subsets of the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Please note: EF6 -

Consider the following tables:

[image]

Obviously this is simplified, but the table DocLink has a column RelatedId that is set to the value of either TestId or LotId. They are differentiated by the value of RelatedTypeId which is a stored as an enum clientside.

I want to be able to define dbSet and dbSet as a filtered subset of DocLink e.g. (and I know this doesn't make sense re: types - it is pseudocode)

```
public DbSet<LotDocLink> LotDocLinks=> (DbSet<LotDocLink>) Set<DocLink>().Where(x=>x.RegisterId==(int)RegisterTypeEnum.Lot);
```

I cannot define views server side as the models connect to 2 different database types (SQL and SQLCE) - the latter doesn't support them. Redesign of this is not an option, the application is legacy and massive.

I specifically want to be able to define navigation on the subset dbsets LotDocLink and TestDocLink.

Is it possible to do table splitting with horizontal compartments instead of vertical? Can I either filter the rows to create a sub-dbset, or define the entities based on an SQL query? Or something else?

Comment: I think you can solve this problem with a discriminator [click here for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance). Tell me if you need a full example. You can use your enum as the discriminator.

Comment: That sounds promising. I'll try it tomorrow and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Pato was indeed the solution here.

I referred to https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph for EF6 reference.

```
public class TestDocLink : DocLink
{
    [NotMapped]
    public int? TestId { get => FkId; set => FkId = value; }
    
    public virtual Test Test{ get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<DocLink>()
            .Map<TestDocLink>(m => m.Requires("RelatedTypeId").HasValue((int)EntityTypeEnum.Test));
```

A couple of tricks - you have to remove RelatedTypeId from the type mapping for DocLink - this is automagically sorted by EF for queries and insertions.

I still haven't figured out how to make a code-only FK reference. I have tried the following, but get an error because TestId is [NotMapped], but TestId has to be NotMapped or you get a different error because it shouldn't map. I will update if I figure this out...

```
public partial class Test
{
    public virtual ICollection<TestDocLink> TestDocLinks{ get; set; }


    partial void InitializePartial() 
    {
        TestDocLinks= new HashSet<TestDocLink>();
    }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<TestDocLink>().HasOptional(a => a.Test).WithMany(b => b.TestDocs)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.TestId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```